# Is my SONY USB flash drive dead?

Tags: windows-7, usb, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, diskpart

I have a following problem: when I plug-in my USB flash drive, it isn't shown in Windows Explorer or recognized by system at all. In device properties, it is shown as:

> USB MEMORY BAR

http://zapodaj.net/5f85a9c58b750.bmp.html

There's no partitions on the drive, so I can't format it:

http://zapodaj.net/e7a4aeee806e6.bmp.html

DISKPART:

> Virtual Disk Service error:
>   There is no media in the device.

HP USB format tool:

> There is no media in the specified device.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank You!

Comment: `There is no media in the device` usually means its dead. Can you post a screenshot of diskmgmt GUI?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens due to interrupted write or format operations. If file system is RAW then following won't work.

Try using diskpart. Open command prompt by start+r and type cmd.
Follow this commands. It will ask for admin permission.

> diskpart
>
> list disk
>
> select disk #   (where # shows number of your usb disk)
>
> format fs=ntfs quick